# How to increase font size of all tds in the table

Tags: html, css

I have table in that some rows are there. I want to increase the td font size to 24 in etire table. How to write css style for td in the head so that font size of all the td data will be increased .

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr class="success">
      <th class="success">a</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="danger">
      <td id="hhh" class="success">filled</td>
      @foreach (var item in Model) {
      <td>@item.Filled.ToString("N2") cm</td>
      }
    </tr>
    <tr class="info">
      <td>Updated time</td>
      @foreach (var item in Model) {
      <td>@item.UpdatedTime</td>
      }
    </tr>
    <tr class="warning">
      <td>Area</td>
      @foreach (var item in Model) {
      <td>@item.Area</td>
      }
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want to increase `font-size` of `th` only?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can nest everything like this:

```
table tbody tr td {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

Or you could keep it simple and just do:

```
td {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

This depends on the context of your CSS, how specific you need to be.  Chances are the second option will do.

Answer (score 2):

Select the `table` selectors and give it a `style` for all `td` elements as simple as that..

```
table td{
    font-size:24px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this code

```
.table td {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

[Live](http://codepen.io/sifulislam/pen/EZBwdp)

Answer (score 1):

U can do that directly in ur html file:

```
<style>
 table td {
   font-size: 24px;
 }
</style>

<table class="table table-striped">
  ...
</table>
```

Or u can create new css file **style.css**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<table class="table table-striped">
  ...
</table>
```

and in the `style.css` gonna be:

```
table td {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
<style>
.mytable td{
  font-size:24px;
}
</style>
<table class="mytable">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>DEF</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do like that.

```
td {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```