# Changing size of font for the whole table

Tags: css, wordpress, inline, gutenberg-blocks

Sorry for reposting this question.  I found a solution here [How to increase font size of all tds in the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337054/how-to-increase-font-size-of-all-tds-in-the-table)

But it says I need 50 points to add a comment so that is why I am creating another questionn on the same topic.  Sorry

I am trying to increase the size of my font for the whole table.  A table I created in latest version of wordpress using the stupid block system.  I tried using this solution in the HTML edit panel of of the block 
    table tbody tr td {
    font-size: 44px};

but it doesn't do anything to the font size when previewing it.  Can anyone help me or tell me where I am supposed to put this code in the line of code so it does what I am trying to do?

By the way I have zero coding experience I have been googling this question for hours now.  Even signed up for a CSS class at Udemy because I am getting so frustrated.  Thank you in advance for your help.

```
<figure class="wp-block-table">

table tbody tr td {  <------this is what I inserted according to other info I found on this site--->
font-size: 44px};

<table class=""><tbody><tr><td><span style="text-decoration: underline;"> 
<strong>McCall Carnival Time</strong></span></td><td><span style="text-decoration: underline;"> 
<strong>McCall Carnival Event Description</strong></span></td><td><span style="text-decoration: 
underline;"><strong>McCall Carnival Event Location</strong> </span>  </td></tr><tr><td></td><td> 
</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>
All Day
</td><td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS code needs to be wrapped in `<style>` tags or included as an external file via a `<link>` tag.

```html
<figure class="wp-block-table">
  <style>
    table tbody tr td {
      font-size: 44px;
    }
  </style>

  <table>
    <!-- The rest of your code -->
  </table>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thanks for coming to my rescue I will give it a try